# Using latex in internet browsing

Tags: browser, latex

Why isn't possible (or feasible) to have latex code written on internet pages: latex being the page's source, like html.

This idea came when I was writing on wikipedia some math article and I realize that the current implementation is quite weak, either in presentation as some things that cannot be written inline.

So, a definitely prettier and simpler approach would be to introduce latex code within the page: the browser would interpret it and, using texlive or equivalent, compile the page with latex generated fonts. This could be inside a HTML, but the generation was using "pure" latex and not some javatex or else.

The latex interpreter could be a plugin of the browser, like Java once was.

This could have profound consequences, like scientific articles be shown on the internet without the need of .pdf or latex based documents be putted on internet in a one click away. The article was code with appropriate packages for internet viewing. The user could at anytime download generate the pdf equivalent of that page.

Any ideas why isn't this feasible /possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In general, using LaTeX for web pages is not a good idea - (La)TeX is designed for exact print output, not for a web view of some web page, where the exact display depends on window/screen sizes, user settings, etc.

Also, at least on my computer, TeX combined with a DVI viewer (or PDFTeX with a PDF viewer) is still quite slower than HTML with a web browser to render a similar sized page ... and there is no easy way to have DOM-like scripting for a LaTeX-page, other than regenerating it on each change. You don't want this.

For these parts where this makes sense (mathematic formulas), this actually already works: There are JavaScript interpreters for subsets of LaTeX (i.e. most of math mode), embedded in a normal HTML document. One example is [MathJax](http://www.mathjax.org/), which is used on the more math-heavy (i.e. scientific) sites in the Stack Exchange network, like [Cryptography Stack Exchange](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/59/taking-advantage-of-one-time-pad-key-reuse).